# Why can't I send Email by NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM?

Tags: sql, email, job-scheduling

I have a SP, which send Email, when I execute by myself, all emails are sent. Now, I configured a Schedule Job, and when it runs, did not send anything, I was searching, and I found when the Job is runing, the send_request_user is NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM, Is there any way to set up this, change it to sa user?

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to change the job Owner to an SA account. You can try this by setting yourself as the job Owner and then executing the job.

NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM is a generic error you get when using a domain user in SQL Server. This error can mean many different things, in this case I'm assuming the job Owner does not have SA permissions and happens to be a domain user.

Comment: I tried to configure to change it to SA account, in General option I choose sa account, but when I configure the Steps, in the advanced options, i choose the users, and only show me 4: dbo, guest, information_schema and sys, I choosed sys and dbo, but any works correctly, what can I do for this?...

Comment: You don't need to change the user per step, you just need to change the Owner of the job.